# Creating a second Activity with a variable layout id

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-activity

I have two Activities: Activity A and Activity B. Activity A consists of a custom ListView and a custom ListView Adapter. When chosing an item of the ListView Activity B appears and displays the user relevant information. When pressing the back/return button Activity B calls finish().

I do not intend to create as many activites as items the ListView has. I want Activity B to be able to change it's layout id. So far my application crashes on every attempt I make to turn the setContentView method variable.

relevant code from Activity A :

```
// code

 if (position == 0 && imaginaryInt == 3) // item position in the ListView 
 {
 ActivityB b = new ActivityB();          
  b.setLayoutID(R.layout.main_c);        // this line causes the crash
   Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),b.getClass());
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

 if (position == 1 && imaginaryInt == 3 ) {...}
```

Acivity B :

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_b);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}  
}
```

Overriding setContentView() in ActivityB and changing params to R.layout.main_c did work!
Unfortunately I ran out of ideas how to manage to change the the layout of ActivityB from ActivityA.

Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: ---SOLUTION---

To be able to change the layout od ActivityB from ActivityA I gave each ListView click a static unique id. In ActivityB the layout is simply changed with the setContentView method and if the row with the unqiue id was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the information you want through the `Intent` used to start the Activity. For example:

```
if (position == 0 && imaginaryInt == 3)
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ActivityB.class);
   intent.putExtra("layout_id", R.layout.main_c); // pass the id as an int extra
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

And then, in your ActivityB class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int layoutId = getIntent().getIntExtra("layout_id", R.layout.default_value);
    setContentView(layoutId);
}
```

Comment: That's the solution to the problem, even better than my way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot operate on layout of ActivityB from ActivityA.
on this line:

```
b.setLayoutID(R.layout.main_c);
```

b is NOT EXISTENT at the time you are trying to call. It will exist only after startActivity.
And even then you, as I remember, cannot do that from activity A - activity B is not synchronized with A.
Use other means: for example create service to signal ActivityB to change layout.